# What is this generated string in firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a mqtt subscriber in python that listens for ESP8266's in different rooms posting their temperature.

When they post the temperature I add the data to firebase using the following:

```
// msq.topic == room name
// msq.payload is the temperature
root.child(msq.topic).push(
    {
        'temperature' : msg.payload.decode("UTF-8"),
        'date_time'   : str(datetime.now()
    }
)
```

When I get the data in firebase it looks like this:
[image]

What is LEB9y19SraBRSGxamvp or where does it come from? (and the other unique ID's)
Can I change it to something more meaningful so that it is easier to get data from firebase? Or have I possibly designed this badly? 
Has anyone any suggestions to make it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a unique push id that's automatically generated when you called `push()`.  If you'd rather write your data in another way, either come up with an ID of your own and use `set()` to write each bit of data, or figure out some other way to represent it.

[Read this blog for more information about push IDs.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)